# document returned by mongoShell query is zero for comparing column in same document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have collection with something similar datastructure

```
{
   id: 1
   limit: {
        max: 10000,
        used: 0     
   }
}
```

and I tried running the below query but it is giving 0 results

```
db.getCollection('promos').aggregate(
[
{ $match: { id:  1} },
{$match: { $expr: {$gt ["limit.max" , "limit.used"]}}}

])
```

I also used the below  query

```
db.getCollection('promos').aggregate(
[
{ $match: { id:  1} },
{$match: { "$limit.max": {$gt: "limit.used"}}}

])
```

None of them is giving the result . Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Missing the `$` prefixes to denote a "field expression" `{$match: { $expr: {$gt: ["$limit.max" , "$limit.used"]}}}`. Without that, you're just comparing "strings", which of course are not "greater than"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to prefix "field expressions" with the `$`. This also can be simply done in a `.find()`

```
db.getCollection('promos').find({
  "id": 1,
  "$expr": { "$gt": [ "$limit.max" , "$limit.used" ] }
})
```

Or a single [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) stage if you really need to use aggregate instead:

```
db.getCollection('promos').aggregate([
  { "$match": {
    "id": 1,
    "$expr": { "$gt": [ "$limit.max" , "$limit.used" ] }
  }}
])
```

That's how [`$expr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) works and you can "mix it" with other regular query operators in the same query or pipeline stage.

Also see [`$gt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/gt/) for general usage examples

Of course if you don't actually even have MongoDB 3.6, then you use [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) instead:

```
db.getCollection('promos').aggregate([
  { "$match": { "id": 1 } },
  { "$redact": {
    "$cond": {
      "if": { "$gt": [ "$limit.max" , "$limit.used" ] },
      "then": "$$KEEP",
      "else": "$$PRUNE"
    }
  }}
])
```

Or use [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/). Works in all versions:

```
db.getCollection('promos').find({
  "id": 1,
  "$where": "this.limit.max > this.limit.used"
})
```

Comment: Assert: command failed: {
 "ok" : 0,
 "errmsg" : "unknown top level operator: $expr",
 "code" : 2,
 "codeName" : "BadValue"
} : aggregate failed

Comment: @made_in_india Did you look at the part of the documentation that says **New in MongoDB 3.6**. You actually need that version to use `$expr`

Comment: It seems I have version `3.4.4`

Comment: @made_in_india Yes it seems you should read documentation first. Read the other solutions above which are actually for your version of MongoDB.

Comment: I tried `$redact` , But when I use `$gt` it give me 0 document and when I used '$lt' it give the required document. It surprising to see the behaviour

Comment: @made_in_india Not on the document in your question, and not on the code as I copied and pasted into the question. You need to actually be running "exactly" the same things. Returns fine for me, so you're not either A: Using the document you posted. B: Using the exact code I posted. Works fine. Check what you are doing.

Comment: @made_in_india Ugghh! Your document has `id` and not `_id` as I wrote in each query. Change the queries to use `id`